# How to pass "context" into the .execute() method of an Operator? (KeyError: 'ti')

Tags: python, dynamic, directed-acyclic-graphs, google-cloud-composer, airflow-2.x

**BACKGROUND**
Airflow version = 2.3.4, Python version = 3.8.
I'm trying to develop a DAG in Google Cloud Composer that can instantiate "n" exact amount of tasks (DataflowOperator) based on the amount of files loaded into a Google Cloud Storage bucket.

**APPROACH**
I've tried to implement this by using Dynamic Tasks in Airflow. I'm using a function with a task decorator that executes a number of DataflowOperators based on the amount of elements in the list passed into this function.

**ERROR**

```
...
File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 1390, in xcom_push
    context['ti'].xcom_push(key=key, value=value, execution_date=execution_date)
KeyError: 'ti'
{taskinstance.py:1408} INFO - Marking task as FAILED.
...
```

**CODE**

```
...
with models.DAG(
    DAG_NAME,
    default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS,
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime.now(),
    catchup=False,
) as dag:
    start = dummy.DummyOperator(task_id='start', trigger_rule='all_success')

    @task
    def dynamic_task_test(sample_list):
        dataflow_operator = DataflowStartFlexTemplateOperator(
            task_id = 'dataflow_task_id',
            project_id = 'project_id',
            location = 'location',
            body = { 'some_parameters' : f'{sample_list}'},
        )
        dataflow_operator.execute(dict())

    start >> dynamic_task_test.expand(sample_list=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

**SCENARIO**
Whenever I try to execute the code above, the DAG is able to:

- create the right amount of mapped instances (based on the length of the list)
- queue, start, and run the right amount of Dataflow jobs

**BUT** throws an error (error code and message snippet above), therefore failing the tasks and the whole DAG. I'm trying to find out what can be causing the error above and ways how to resolve it.

**QUESTIONS**

1. What do the error code and message mean?
2. What must I do correctly to resolve the issue?
3. How should I properly pass the "context" into the .execute() method of the Operator?
4. Do you have any advice or idea on how I can do it differently?

Comment: Your dynamic task is executed for each element in the list ?

Comment: @MazlumTosun yes, that is correct.

Comment: The problem with this approach, you have to execute your inside the method and it cause error in the execute method. I can propose other approaches, if your are interested

Comment: @MazlumTosun I would definitely appreciate your insights and approach regarding this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `@task`, you have to execute the operator inside the method and the call to `execute` method causes an error.

I propose you 2 other approaches :

#### Solution 1 :

You can do a classical `for loop` in the code and execute `Dataflow` jobs in parallel, example :

```py
import airflow
from airflow.operators import dummy
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataflow import DataflowStartFlexTemplateOperator

with airflow.DAG(
        "dag_id", default_args={}, schedule_interval=None,
) as dag:
    start = dummy.DummyOperator(task_id='start', trigger_rule='all_success')

    sample_list = ['A', 'B', 'C']

    for element in sample_list:
        dataflow_operator = DataflowStartFlexTemplateOperator(
            task_id=f'dataflow_task_id_{element}',
            project_id='project_id',
            location='location',
            body={'some_parameters': element},
        )

        start >> dataflow_operator
```

It will execute each `Dataflow` job in parallel and represent each Dataflow task in the DAG.

#### Solution 2 :

Use a task group that build the list of `DataflowStartFlexTemplateOperator`.
It's similar to the solution 1 but more elegant in the `DAG` graph.

It will represent a task group in the graph, that can be expandable.
When we expand it, we see all the Dataflow tasks inside.

Example :

```py
from typing import List

import airflow
from airflow.decorators import task_group
from airflow.operators import dummy
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataflow import DataflowStartFlexTemplateOperator


@task_group()
def launch_dataflow_operators(sample_list: List[str]) -> List[DataflowStartFlexTemplateOperator]:
    return list(map(to_dataflow_operator, sample_list))


def to_dataflow_operator(element) -> DataflowStartFlexTemplateOperator:
    return DataflowStartFlexTemplateOperator(
        task_id=f'dataflow_task_id_{element}',
        project_id='project_id',
        location='location',
        body={'some_parameters': element},
    )


with airflow.DAG(
        "dag_id", default_args={}, schedule_interval=None,
) as dag:
    start = dummy.DummyOperator(task_id='start', trigger_rule='all_success')

    sample_list = ['A', 'B', 'C']

    start >> launch_dataflow_operators(sample_list)
```

- The `@task_group` method returns the list of `DataflowStartFlexTemplateOperator`
- We can then execute it as an usual operator in the `DAG` : `start >> launch_dataflow_operators(sample_list)`

I didn't had the time to execute the second solution on my side but the idea is here.

Comment: Hi @mazlumtosun, In Solution 1,  how to structure the dependency, in case, we have a task `task3_at_last`, which we want to run after all instances of  `dataflow_operator` have finished executing.